# THREE.js proper controls inclusion with require.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, requirejs

My goal is to add MapControls to my application, like in this example:
https://github.com/felixpalmer/amd-three.js

This example works fine with TrackballControlls. But MapControls require definition of THREE.MOUSE. So I updated version of three.min.js to current version and nothing works now. I get these errors:

ReferenceError: THREE is not defined TrackballControls.js:5:1

ReferenceError: THREE is not defined MapControls.js:18:1

TypeError: THREE.MapControls is not a constructor

config.js

```
// Configure Require.js
var require = {
  // Default load path for js files
  baseUrl: 'js/app',
  shim: {
    // --- Use shim to mix together all THREE.js subcomponents
    'threeCore': { exports: 'THREE' },
    'TrackballControls': { deps: ['threeCore'], exports: 'THREE' },
    'MapControls': { deps: ['threeCore'], exports: 'THREE' },   
    // --- end THREE sub-components
    'detector': { exports: 'Detector' },
    'stats': { exports: 'Stats' }
  },
  // Third party code lives in js/lib
  paths: {
    // --- start THREE sub-components
    three: '../lib/three',
    threeCore: '../lib/three.min',
    TrackballControls: '../lib/controls/TrackballControls',
    MapControls: '../lib/controls/MapControls', 
    // --- end THREE sub-components
    detector: '../lib/Detector',
    stats: '../lib/stats.min',
    // Require.js plugins
    text: '../lib/text',
    shader: '../lib/shader',
    // Where to look for shader files
    shaders: '../shaders'
  }
};
```

three.js

```
// As THREE.js comes with many addons/plugins mix them all into one three object here
define( ["threeCore", "TrackballControls", "MapControls"], function( threeCore ) { 
  return threeCore;
} );
```

Comment: The example that you have linked to is over 5 years old, three.js has changed a lot since then and now uses es2015 exports. But, in your code, you have `MapControls: '../lib/controls/MapControls'` which is looking in the for MapControls inside the [lib/controls](https://github.com/felixpalmer/amd-three.js/tree/master/js/lib/controls) folder, where it does not exist. You could try putting it in there.

Comment: I put it there. It is there and It gives this error:

ReferenceError: 
THREE is not defined MapControls.js:18:1